# Save as dialog is not appearing in any "metro" app on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, microsoft-surface

I have a problem that Save dialog is not appearing in any metro app. Only save as dialog is not working, I think. For example if I find a download link and press it - everything is fine, but if I press right click on picture and press save - nothing happening. And in any modern app pressing "save" button is not working, but "save by updating original file" is working fine (updating file). When in IE or any other app I click "save as" button, save line appearing for 0.1 sec and then disappears. No saving could be done. Do you know how to solve it?

Once again, it is a problem with all modern apps where there is an option to save something on disk. It started 2 days ago and I haven't figured out what was the reason.

I have tried:

- Restoring to the earlier point - problem is still here
- sfc /scannow - all fine, no vulnerability here
- Creating new account shows the same behavior- save dialog fleshes and disappears
- Modern UI App troubleshooter and check.
- Scanned for new hardware, nothing, tried update video driver - it says it is up to date

[This](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/2/4/F24D0C03-4181-4E5B-A23B-5C3A6B5974E3/apps.diagcab)
shows several problems:

1. Some apps do not have needed permissions - I do not think it is a problem.
2. Check for missing or corrupt files - not solved, but shows 100% and no vulnerability
3. Service registration is missing or corrupt - fixed by resetting
4. Display adapter driver might be out of date - not solved

Problem is still here.

P. S. I have Windows 8.1, Surface Pro 2.

Comment: Your Metro apps not having permissions is a problem